# custom query for both category and pages using global $wpdb;

Tags: categories, customization, pages, query

I have a custom query returning categories, but I also need to return some pages with a particular post ids. How would I add those? They obviously have no taxonomy and are page post types.

Below is my query so far:

```
protected function _getPostByCategory($category) {
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->terms.name = '$category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC");
```

Comment: Why must this be SQL?

Answer (score 1):

What about using the UNION? Just an example:

```
(SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts (with JOIN and WHERE as needed))

UNION

(SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts (with WHERE to select pages)) 

GROUP BY/ORDER BY
```

The select(s) must be in parenthesis to use an order by for the whole union result.

As a second option, you can use a plugin to enable the categories and tags on pages, I used it many times to classify even the pages inside a category.

The call to be fired on WordPress "init" hook is:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
```

and while editing the page you'll have the classical category chooser like the one of regular posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MySQL query expert but a few `OR` statements might do the trick.

```
OR $wpdb->posts.ID = 2
OR $wpdb->posts.ID = 703
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page'
```

So in the context of your query it's like this.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(" SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms ON($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
WHERE $wpdb->terms.name = '$category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'

OR $wpdb->posts.ID = 2
OR $wpdb->posts.ID = 703
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page'

GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC");
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is almost working, but the post ids are returning within the category responses and not separately. So for example, a category of "news" has these two posts(pages) tagged onto the end. Any suggestions as to how to separate them?

Comment: Sorry but that's beyond my talents.